# No. of $t,s \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t)=f(s)$ for a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question is  :

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Let

$$A=\{ (t,s) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]   : t\neq s ; f(t)=f(s)\}$$

The number of elements in $A$ is...... ?

As $f(0)=f(1)$ and i should take care of continuity of $f$ I some how feel that the figure should be like :

[image]

which is telling me that there are infinitely many points $(t,s)$ such that $t\neq s$ but $f(t)=f(s)$

I am not sure if this should be the case and if it is so, I am not sure how to write this precisely.

I would be thankful if some one can help me to clear this problem..

Thank you

P.S : This is the first time (after so many years) I am using Paint. So, the figure looks very awkward but please adjust with that.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. To made it precise, you need both extremum value theorem and intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I am getting confused how to make use of intermediate value theorem... given any $b : f(0)\leq b \leq f(1)$ I wuld have an $a\in[0,1]$ such that $f(a)=b$ but then $f(0)=f(1)$ :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Use extreme value thm. first, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, assume $f\not\equiv C$, since then this is trivial ($A = [0,1]^2$)
Then use the extreme value theorem together with $f(0) = f(1)$ to get at least one extremum within $(0,1)$ (if both were on the border, we'd be in the first case).
Call this extremum $(\xi, f(\xi))$ and assume it is a maximum (else consider $-f$), then by intermediate value theorem we have
$$\forall \eta \in (f(0), f(\xi)) \quad \exists
\begin{cases}
\alpha\in (0,\xi) & f(\alpha) = \eta \\
\beta\in (\xi, 1) & f(\beta) = \eta
\end{cases}$$
And thus
$$\forall \eta \in (f(0), f(\xi)) \qquad \exists \alpha \neq \beta: (\alpha, \beta) \in A$$
Since $(f(0), f(\xi))$ is infinite because $f\not\equiv C$, $A$ is also infinite for this case.

Comment: what does it mean when you say $f\neq C$? do you mean non constant function?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It means $\nexists C \in \mathbb R : f(x) = C \quad \forall x\in [0,1]$ which means that $f$ is not constant.

Comment: This is very helpful.. Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Happy to help :) If you have any further questions on this topic, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have a local maximum(this can also be done if we have a local minimum).

If this local maximum is the only one ,then you can take the set of the graph that is before you get the maximum and name it $A$ and the other part of the graph name it $B$. Then you can project
perpendicularly $A$ to $B$. So you have infinite as an answer in your question.

Same you do if there are two local maximums. You find one and get $A$ from the previous local minimum to the local maximum and $B$ from the local maximum to the next local minimum.

This can be done because $f$ is continuous on a connected set and because $f(0)\neq f(1)$, so the extrema cannot both be on the border $\{0,1\}$ without $f$ being constant.

If $f$ is constant,then also you can infinite pairs.

Comment: You should justify why you have at least one of them within $(0,1)$, else your argument wont work (for example on $f(x) = x$)

Comment: @AlexR ,does $f(x)=x$ imply that $f(0)=f(1)$?

Comment: This is, what's missing in "This can be done because $f$ is continuous on a connected set"

Comment: You should still add $f(0) = f(1)$ somewhere to force one extremum into the inner... (-1) removed.

Comment: @AlexR, i think it's done "This can be done because f is continuous on a connected set and because f(x)≠x then f has curvity". thns btw,didn't notice

Comment: It's still wrong. You can have any function $f(0) \neq f(1)$ constructed such that both extrema are at the border. For example use
$$f(x) = a + (b-a) x$$
(the linear interpolation). Also, there are non-$C^1$ functions with this property so $f(0) = f(1)$ is the "optimal" constraint if you don't want $C^1$ and a zero in $f'$ within $(0,1)$.

Comment: @AlexR, and then if for example $f$ is the upper border of the square ,then $f$ is constant,and it's done.If it's not constant then $f$ will have at least a local minimum,and then it's done

Comment: No it will not. Chose $a \neq b$ and you have _no_ local extrema within $(0,1)$ thus not allowing you to partition.